# apt-get gives "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code"

Tags: debian, apt

So I was trying to install Cython on my Debian machine, and in the installation it gave me the error code:

```
 Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now as the pure blooded professional student that I am, after just waking up, I didnt think more of it, and thought Id look at it better later. However now when trying to install anything, or update, apt-get gives me the following

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
cython
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo dpkg --configure -a gives the following

```
Setting up cython (0.25.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package cython (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cython
```

sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cython (0.25.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package cython (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  cython
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

Comment: I think the relevant part is `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' maybe this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser#comment56408252_14087705) might help?

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg -C` output anything?

Comment: @StefanM Yes, it did indeed help, I had to change my Python version back to 2.7, then run sudo apt purge cython. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To unblock `apt`, you’ll need to remove the `cython` package:

```
sudo apt purge cython
```

Fixing the `cython` installation is likely to be a bit more involved (see the question comments).